# Issues using mysqli prepare with ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working on updating a website to avoid any chance of MySQL injection attacks. This led me to use mysqli with Php.

I'm now getting this error when I try to execute a search on the website:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in ...
```

The search is meant to take a users input from a textbox and search through the database for records containing the particular string entered by a user. The code I am trying to run is as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM periodicals WHERE MATCH(author, title, type, keyword, citation) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY ? ? LIMIT ?,?";

$stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);

$stmt -> bind_param("sssii", $param1, $param2, $param3, $param4, param5);

$param1 = $trimmed; //contains a keyword entered by user to search for
$param2 = $column;  // contains which column to sort by (selected by user)
$param3 = $sort;    // contains 'ASC' or 'DESC' for sorting (selected by user)
$param4 = (empty($s)) ? 0 : $s; //contains offset for LIMIT
$param5 = $limit; // contains number of values to retrieve
```

I used `var_dmup($stmt)` and it returned false which means that the call to `prepare()` was not successful.

I read that an incorrect sql query may cause this error and checked to make sure the query was working correctly by running the sql (with values instead of ?'s) directly on the database and encountered no errors or warnings about it.

I then did some experimenting around. I think I narrowed the problem down to the `ORDER BY ? ?` part of the SQL query as the code will run and load the correct result when the second `?` is changed to either `ASC` or `DESC` and the `bind_param()` is adjusted to match as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM periodicals WHERE MATCH(author, title, type, keyword, citation) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY ? DESC LIMIT ?,?";

$stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);

$stmt -> bind_param("ssii", $param1, $param2, $param4, param5);
```

The values for `$param3` is set to be either `DESC` or `ASC` earlier in the code. I used `var_dump()` in testing to make sure of this when writing the code that stores the value into `$sort`, so I don't believe that it's feeding an incorrect value into the query.

If anyone has any suggestions at all about how I might be able to solve this problem or what is going wrong I would be very grateful.

Comment: Yes, you can't use placeholders there. Only values/strings can be bound. But the ORDER BY clause would need an identifier / column name. Those can't be substituted with `?`. Neither can a SQL keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bind_param` is used to prevent `SQL Injection` as you know. It does so by making sure that you can only enter values and not alter the actual `SQL` statement.

If you try to put in `ASC` or `DESC` as params, you'll notice it can't be done. Simply because that would mean you are altering the `SQL` statement.

You should simply check the value on its own and enter it in the query.

```
<?php
$ascOrDesc = ($uservalue=="DESC") ? "DESC" : "ASC";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM periodicals WHERE MATCH(author, title, type, keyword, citation) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY ? " . $ascOrDesc;
?>
```

Keep in mind that if you use `?` for the column name in the `ORDER BY` class, you are not actually ordering by that columns value.

If you would enter `Name` as the column, you would be sorting all rows by the value 'name' and not the column `name`. So there will be no ordering at all, because every row is matched against the same value.

Comment: Thank you. I can see where I was going wrong now and know how to sort it.

Comment: Also thank you for pointing out about the other ordering issue. It was literally the next bug to crop up for me and I'm sure I would've been pulling my hair out over it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a comma between arguments to an `order by`.  So, if you had two keys, you would do:

```
ORDER BY ?, ?
```

But you want the second one to be `ASC` or `DESC`.  You can't pass these in directly as parameters.  You could build them into the string, which should be safe because you would only put in `ASC` or `DESC` based on logic in php.  Alternatively, you could pass in a string and do:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN ? = 'DESC' THEN ? END) DESC,
         ? ASC
```

When first expression evaluates to true, then you use the value.  Otherwise, all the values are `NULL` -- and the second clause takes effect.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying that for me. I had thought it would be okay to pass in as a parameter as it would be a string but that does make sense. I already have the logic done to validate it to make sure it's DESC/ASC so I'm going to build it into the string using concatenation.

Comment: @nee_s . . . In general, you cannot pass in syntactic elements of SQL as parameters.  In addition, you cannot pass in table names or column aliases.